# uploadify not attaching image

Tags: uploadify, silverstripe

I'm working on a pagetype with a Imagedataobjectmanager. In slide show, files getting uploaded in CMS area.

The problem I'm having is, in the uploadify popup, when you upload a file, it hits 100%, and disappears. The file has been uploaded to the assets/uploads folder but it doesn't attach.

One mediocre fix is to upload in the File & Images to the right folder, go to your page and import them, however when you do that, it moves the selected files into the assets/Uploads folder, but it does attach them.

Changed the permission of the folder to 777, no luck. But surprosingly, file & images attaches the photos into the same folder

Thanks

Comment: silverstripe version and some code would be helpful

Comment: Silverstripe version is 2.4. Used dataobject_manager with this uploadify.Followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432739/silverstripe-uploadify-add-fields

Comment: just a note concerning dom's behaviour of copying the files on import, there's a setting to prevent this: https://github.com/unclecheese/DataObjectManager/search?q=copyOnImport&ref=cmdform